# Cases of attributive adjectives describing units of time (Month, weekdays, etc)

Tags: declension

*Treffen wir uns nächsten Freitag in demselben Cafe?*

Is the reason for "nächsten" taking the weak dative ending because it is the short versrion of "Am nächsten Freitag"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the grammatical case used with a preposition and the case used without a preposition are two entirely different things.

If a preposition is used, the case is basically determined by the preposition. With temporal *an*, dative is used.

Without a preposition, accusative is used. There is also a temporal genitive but it is no longer used today except for some relicts with temporal adverbs like "nachts".

The *nächsten Freitag* in your example is not a weak dative but a strong accusative.

Comment: A degenerate genitive is also possible for weekdays: *Treffen wir uns immer freitags?*

Answer (score 1):

Nein. Zeitangaben können mit einer Vielzahl von Präpositionen versehen sein, die dann jeweils ihren Fall verlangen, aber es ist auch möglich, Zeitangaben ohne Präposition zu machen. Diese stehen dann im Akkusativ.

Beispiele:

- **alleinstehende Jahreszahlen**

  > Alina wird erst **2021** mit ihrem Studium fertig sein.
- **Anfang, Mitte, Ende**

  > Das Projekt wird **Anfang 2020** in die heiße Phase gehen.
  >   Ich fliege **Mitte Juni** nach Rom.
  >   Herr Huber wird uns **Ende Woche 29** einen Besuch abstatten.
- **vorige, diese, nächste**

  > Man konnte **voriges Jahr** kaum Maikäfer sehen.
  >   Jürgen ist **diese Woche** in Spanien.
  >   Treffen wir uns **nächsten Freitag** in demselben Cafe?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But I am afraid I still do not fully understand why "nächsten Freitag" is in dative here. Is it because it signifies time thus being a temporal adjective? In the meantime, how about this sentence? *Sie sehen den ganzen Tag fern* Why is "den ganzen Tag" in accusative here? I am very confused

Comment: It isn't in dative case. It is accusative case!

Comment: My bad. Now I realize it